# Why does docker pseudo-tty mangle output when piped to other command?

Tags: bash, docker, tty

Why does pseudo-tty option in docker modify output when docker output is piped to other commands?

Docker uses `CRLF` line endings when run with `-t` option. So here's my 2 commands with `CR` added to other one to make their outputs identical.

```
❯ docker run --rm -ti bash bash -c "echo -n $'\n\n\n'" | od -c
0000000  \r  \n  \r  \n  \r  \n

❯ docker run --rm bash bash -c "echo -n $'\r\n\r\n\r\n'" | od -c
0000000  \r  \n  \r  \n  \r  \n
```

Both commands piped to while read -loop (I'd expect both outputs to be identical)

```
❯ while read -r out; do echo A; done < <(docker run --rm -ti bash bash -c "echo -n $'\n\n\n'")
A
 A
  A

❯ while read -r out; do echo A; done < <(docker run --rm bash bash -c "echo -n $'\r\n\r\n\r\n'")
A
A
A
```

Why does this happen? Why does pseudo-tty break output? Shouldn't it only tell docker that input is terminal device?

Of course not using `-it` for non-interactive scripts is a valid solution for this, but doesn't answer 'why'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the docker client sets the stdin and the stdout in the raw mode when `--tty` option is provided. There is call to `setRawTerminal(streams)` in function `setupInput()` defined in `cli/command/container/hijack.go`, which sets both the stdin and the stdout in the raw mode ([github link](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/6f8070deb2207aa255fd2ae8a1e305e3d79797f6/cli/command/container/hijack.go#L81)).

As far as I know, this raw mode then propagates back to the terminal you are using. You can notice this by removing `stty -raw` from the following example and running them in order.

In short, raw mode means that the terminal should not do any line processing, i.e. terminal doesn't act on CR (`\r`).

Simple demostration without the docker client:

```
❯ while read -r out; do echo A; done < <(bash -c "stty raw; echo -n $'\n\n\n'")   
A
 A
  A

❯ while read -r out; do echo A; done < <(bash -c "stty -raw; echo -n $'\n\n\n'")
A
A
A
```

or just:

```
❯ stty raw; for i in {0..2}; do echo A; done
A
 A
  A

❯ stty -raw; for i in {0..2}; do echo A; done
A
A
A
```